# Django IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")

Tags: mysql, django

This is my models.py

```
class Cfituser(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
socialid = models.IntegerField(null=True)
accesstoken = models.CharField(max_length=255L, null = True)
class Meta:
    db_table = 'CfitUser'
def __str__(self):  
      return "%s's profile" % self.user  

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_cfituser(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):  
    if created:  
        Cfituser.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

This is my views.py

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def users_create(request, format = None):
"""
List all users, or create a new user.
"""
if request.method == 'GET':
    cfituser = Cfituser.objects.all()
    serializer = CfituserSerializer(cfituser, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

elif request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = CfituserSerializer(data=request.DATA)
    if serializer.is_valid():
            print serializer.data
            user = User.objects.create_user(username = serializer.data['socialid'])
            cfituser = Cfituser.objects.get(user = user)
            cfituser.accesstoken = serializer.data['accesstoken']
            cfituser.socialid = serializer.data['socialid']
            cfituser.save()
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Whenever there is a HTTP Post request, my database tables are filled in as expected but this error keeps popping up. I've tried almost every solution available on SO but I'm stuck with this.

I have tried `user = models.OneToOneField(User, null = True)` but this leads to two entries in my database table, one with `user_id = NULL` and one with `user_id = actualvalue`.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: your lines `cfituser = Cfituser.objects.get(user = user)          cfituser.user = user` are completely wrong

Comment: @suhail Ah sorry cfit.user = user was meant to be commented out. It isn't a part of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving by default commits the entry to the database, to prevent that, pass `commit=False` to `save()`, and then do your customizations.

```
 serializer = serializer.save(commit=False)

 user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username = serializer.socialid) 
 cfituser, created = Cfituser.objects.get_or_create(user = user)
 # cfituser.user = user This line is unnecessary
 cfituser.accesstoken = serializer.accesstoken
 cfituser.socialid = serializer.socialid

 cfituser.save()
 serializer.save()
```

You are also duplicating your efforts because your signal will also attempt to create a user.  If you are on django 1.5, use [customized user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user); and for social registration/oauth, use [`django-social-auth`](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth).

Comment: `save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit'`. The REST framework doesn't support that unfortunately. I am looking at the customised user model.

Answer (score 0):

`OneToOneField` means, in `Cfituser.user` the reverse side of the relation will directly return a single object(`user.cfituser` gives `Cfituser`). SO `Cfituser.user` must be unique through out the table(one and only one).

```
class Cfituser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    socialid = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    accesstoken = models.CharField(max_length=255L, null = True)
    def __unicode__(self):  
         return "%s's profile" % self.user.username  


def users_create(request, format = None):
"""
List all users, or create a new user.
"""
    if request.method == 'GET':
        cfituser = Cfituser.objects.all()
        serializer = CfituserSerializer(cfituser, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data) 
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = CfituserSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print serializer.data
            user = User.objects.create_user(username = serializer.data['socialid'])                
            Cfituser(user = user,accesstoken = serializer.data['accesstoken'],socialid = serializer.data['socialid']).save()
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: This raises a `IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '2' for key 'user_id'")`

Comment: @Nikhita why did you use `user = models.OneToOneField(User)`, try `user = models.ForeignKey(User)`

Comment: @Nikhita if you use `user = models.OneToOneField(User)` you can use `user.cfituser` where `user` is `User` field

Comment: True, but the behaviour is the same. I still get the same error.

Comment: @Nikhita I have few questions? does a `User` can be more than one `Cfituser` i mean same user with different accesstoken?.

Comment: No. Each `Cfituser` is mapped to a single `User` with a unique accesstoken and socialid.

Comment: @Nikhita if you try this `>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User`|
`>>> user = User.objects.create_user('john')`|
`>>> user = User.objects.create_user('john')`| so there is the error `return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
IntegrityError: column username is not unique`

Comment: @Nikhita you may be trying to create same user twice. that is why the error

Comment: Thanks for your help Suhail.. I'll keep that in mind.. Still working on it.